# Using find to return certain filenames (without path) in a directory

Tags: find, regular-expression, directory, filenames

I would like to use `find` to return files with a specific filename, in this case: Files that do not begin with `_`.

I learned I could use

```
find . ! '(' -name '_*' ')'
```

But, I want it to return the filenames without the preceding pathname. Is there any way I could use cmd `basename` to do this in bash?

I also welcome any other command, like `ls` that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is like as below as well as if you want *files name* only to print, using `find` and [`shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).:

```
find /path/to -type f -name "[!_]*" -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "${1##*/}"' _ {} \;
```

Or we can use `find` with `-execdir` combination if you don't mind the leading `./`.

```
find /path/to -type f -name "[!_]*" -execdir printf '%s\n' {} +
```

You would use `find -type f ! -name "_*" ...` as well.

Comment: If I wanted to specify a path, could I input: `find /home/user/dir1 -type f -not -name "_*"`to return certain files under that path, for example?

Comment: No, actually, `! -name ...` is more correct in `find`. `-not` is not a standard keyword but is supported by at least GNU find. (In the same way `-and` and `-or` are non-standard, `-a` and `-o` are the standard ones.) Also the patterns recognized by `find` have nothing to do with the shell, you could use `find -name "[^_]*"` regardless of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f ! -name "_*" -printf "%f\n"
```

The `printf` with `%f` is a GNU extension of POSIX `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `basename` - by passing it as an argument to the `-exec` action:

```
find . ! -name '_*' -exec basename {} \;
```

(your grouping parentheses are unnecessary, since there's no issue of operator precedence).

Alternatively, if you have GNU `find`, its `-printf` action provides a format specifier for the plain filename:

> ```
>      %f     File's  name  with  any leading directories removed (only
>             the last element).
> ```

so

```
find . ! -name '_*' -printf '%f\n'
```